# Creating multiple mandatory fields in workflow

Tags: youtrack

I have a requirement for multiple fields to be set whenever an issue is created.

I tried this

```
rule Mandatory 

when <issue created or updated> { 
  Swimlane.required("Must have a swimlane"); 
  UtgmsVehicleName.required("Must be attached to a vehicle "); 
  Subsystem.required("Subsystem must be set"); 
  Assignee.required("Assignee must be set"); 
  Fix versions.required("Fix versions must be set/"); 
}
```

What happens is that it continually asks for all the fields to be set. What is the best way to fulfil the requirement.

Based on Alex's suggestion i got this

```
rule MandatoryFields 

when !isReported() { 
  var assigneeSet = Assignee != null; 
  var subSystemSet = Subsystem != null && Subsystem != {No subsystem}; 
  var fixedVersionSet = Fix versions != null; 
  var assigneeValue = Assignee.oldValue; 

  var messageValue = "Mandatory fields:"; 
  if (!assigneeSet) { 
    messageValue = messageValue + " Assignee"; 
  } 
  if (!subSystemSet) { 
    messageValue = messageValue + " Subsystem"; 
  } 
  if (!fixedVersionSet) { 
    messageValue = messageValue + " FixedVersion"; 
  } 
  assert (assigneeSet && subSystemSet && fixedVersionSet): messageValue; 

  if (assigneeSet) { 
    Assignee = assigneeValue; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like

```
var noSwimlane = Swimlane == null;
var noSubsystem = Subsystem == null;
...
var message = "You need to fill the following fields: ";
if (noSwimlane) {
  message += "Swimlane";
}
...
assert !(noSwimlane || noSubsystem || ...) : message;
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the idea, i tried doing the same thing but it doesnt recognise += so i changed that to     messageValue = "" + messageValue + " ,Subsystem";  and still no joy? Cheers

Comment: Not sure I get your point. What was the problem with messageValue = "" + messageValue + " ,Subsystem"; ?

Comment: Alex , thanks I got the code working in the end,the problem is that if you fill in a field for example, the assert wipes out the value you set so I was thinking I could store each fields value and then re assign at the end after the assert ? Doesnt seem to work. Ive added the code to the question. thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately, assert really reverts the transaction.